# Postgres replication with referenced files

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a postgres database which contains references to files on the filesystem. These references are simple `VARCHAR` values, so I understand there is no referential integrity guaranteed:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    username VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    age INTEGER,
    template VARCHAR(100) -- Filepath of a file on disk
);

INSERT INTO
    user   (username,   age,   template)
    VALUES ('bob',      32,    '/templates/cool-template.html');
```

This is fine, the lack of referential integrity is not a concern. *But* now I go and set up standard streaming replication (I follow the tutorial on [this page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication) under the "How To Use" heading).

**What is the best way for me to replicate any filesystem files (e.g. "cool-template.html") along with postgres db content?** I don't want to store files in the database. I am already aware I can independently `rsync` any files, but is there a better way? Does postgres provide some sort of hook which could trigger a file to be backed up?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution as you said is to use a dummy rsync (triggered via cron or a hook), just make sure you're not only syncing existing files (if so you'll sever sync the deletion of a file).

```
rsync -avh source/ dest/ --delete
```

You can also use a [amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/s3/) or [google](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets) bucket to store your data (it won't be replicated but this is still a pretty safe and highly available solution).

If you're confident enough you can play with [DRBD](https://docs.linbit.com/) and [Ceph](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rados/) to create a storage cluster (not advised unless you really know what you're doing and you have more than two nodes).

I'd personally go for amazon or google shared storage : low risk, not much maintenance, simple to understand and use.